# Alamofire, response handler performance issues

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am working on performance for my application and after debuging via instruments I've got a problem with requests. I am using `DispatchQueue` for each of them and also grouping them via `DispatchGroup`. Could someone have a look and point where am I doing mistakes ?

[image: Request]

Here is a `responseHandler` :

```
func responseHandler(dataResponse: DataResponse<Data>, completion: @escaping (Data, NetworkCode) -> Void) {

        guard (dataResponse.response?.statusCode) != nil else { completion(Data(), .error); return }
        guard Connectivity.Instance.isReachability else { completion(Data(), .noInternetConnection); return }
        // Response must be different than 401 - 401 code means we fucked up request.
        if dataResponse.response?.statusCode == 401 {
        // TODO: Handle message from server.
            completion(Data(), .error)
            return
        }
        // Return data from resonse if everything went ok ( status code 200 )
        guard let data = dataResponse.data else { completion(Data(), .error); return }
        completion(data, .success)
    }
```

I've basically checking request status codes and internet connection.

The queue : `final let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.cnoon.response-queue", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: .concurrent)`

The call :

// Create dispatch group.

```
            let group = DispatchGroup()

            // Get first data.
            group.enter()
            let queryParams = self.buildQueryParams(requestType: .getFirstData(token))
            self.firstRequestWith(queryParams, completion: {
                // Here is a createRequest method call - inside firstRequestWith
                print("1 request")
                group.leave()
            })

            // Get second data.
            group.enter()
            let queryParams = self.buildQueryParams(requestType: .getSecondData(token))
            self.secondRequestWith(queryParams, completion: {
                // Here is a createRequest method call - inside secondRequestWith
                print("1 request")
                group.leave()
            })

            group.wait()

            group.notify(queue: .main, work: DispatchWorkItem(block: {
                print("Main")
            }))
```

`buildQueryParams` method returns dictionary of type `[String: AnyObject]`.

Am I well understanding Multi-threading Alamofire requests ?

Thanks in advance!